# Proof of iterated expectation property

Tags: probability

I want to compute the expectation $E\{(y-\pi)^{2}\}$ where $\pi$ is a function of $x$. Expanding the product, we get this:

$$E\{(y-\pi)^{2}\} = E\{(y-\hat{y})^{2}\} + 2E\{(y-\hat{y})(\hat{y}-\pi)\} + E\{(\hat{y}-\pi)^{2}\}$$

with $\hat{y}$ as $E\{y|x\}$

According to the [book](http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/THIRDMET/MYLECTURES/1REGRESS.pdf) (page 2) where I read that, the second term should be $0$:

\begin{align}E\{(y-\hat{y})(\hat{y}-\pi)\}&=\int_{x}\int_{y}(y-\hat{y})(\hat{y}-\pi)f(x,y)dxdy\\&\int_{x}\int_{y}(y-\hat{y})f(y|x)dy(\hat{y}-\pi)f(x)dx\\&=0\end{align}

The reason that term is $0$ is because of the following equation:

$$\int(y-\hat{y})f(y|x)dy = E(y|x)-E(y|x)=0$$

The first part $\int yf(y|x)dx$ is obvious but I can't prove the second one. I think it's right because I have seen the [property](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.vwl.uni-mannheim.de/mammen/notes5.pdf) (page 4) $E\{E\{Y|X\}|f(x)\}=E\{Y|f(x)\}$ which makes the last equation true. However, I can't prove that property.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming the existence of densities in your question, so here is a completely elementary proof using only Fubini's theorem (for interchanging the order of integration) and simple properties of joint probability densities

\begin{eqnarray*}
  E_x \left[ E \left[ y|x \right] \right] & = & \int E \left[ y|x \right] f
  \left( x \right) \mathrm{d} x\\
  & = & \int \left( \int yf \left( y|x \right) \mathrm{d} y \right) f \left(
  x \right) \mathrm{d} x\\
  & = & \int \int yf \left( y|x \right) f \left( x \right) \mathrm{d} x
  \mathrm{d} y\\
  & = & \int \int yf \left( x|y \right) f \left( y \right) \mathrm{d} x
  \mathrm{d} y\\
  & = & \int y \underbrace{\left( \int f \left( x|y \right) \mathrm{d} x
  \right)}_{= 1} f \left( y \right) \mathrm{d} y\\
  & = & \int yf \left( y \right) \mathrm{d} y\\
  & = & E \left[ y \right]
\end{eqnarray*}

This is not the best way to prove the result.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm assuming the existence of densities. Why do you say this is not the best to prove this result?

Comment: @RobertSmith Mainly because it is possible to prove it under much weaker conditions.

Comment: @RobertSmith To see a nicer (and shorter) proof, but one that appeals to Kolmogorov's abstract measure-theoretic definition of condition expectation, you could look at Ash and Doléans-Dade's "Probability and Measure Theory" theorem 5.5.4 (second edition p.223)

Comment: That's not a problem since I'm starting to get used to this kind of calculations. However, thanks for the reference.